# Proving order relation

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, axioms, ordered-fields

Suppose $F = \mathbb{Q}^2$ is a field equipped with the following operations:

Addition: Defined entrywise i.e.

$$(x_1, x_2) + (y_1, y_2) = (x_1 + y_1, x_2 + y_2)$$

Multiplication:

$$(x_1, x_2) \cdot (y_1, y_2) = (x_1y_1 + 2x_2y_2, x_1y_2 + x_2y_1)$$

Given $(x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2) \in F$, define $(x_1, x_2) < (y_1, y_2) \iff x_1 + x_2 < y_1 + y_2$, as defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that this is an ordered relation on $F$.

My attempt:

Trichotomy: Choose $(x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2) \in F$.

Case 1: $x_1 + x_2 < y_1 + y_2 \implies (x_1, x_2) < (y_1, y_2)$

Case 2: $x_1 + x_2 > y_1 + y_2 \implies y_1 + y_2 < x_1 + x_2 \implies (y_1, y_2) < (x_1, x_2) \implies (x_1, x_2) > (y_1, y_2)$

Case 3: $x_1 + x_2 = y_1 + y_2 \implies (x_1, x_2) = (y_1, y_2)$

Therefore, trichotomy is satisfied.

Transitivity: Consider $(x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2), (z_1, z_2) \in F$. Assume that $(x_1, x_2) < (y_1, y_2)$ and $(y_1, y_2) < (z_1, z_2)$. We have that:

$(x_1, x_2) < (y_1, y_2) \implies x_1 + x_2 < y_1 + y_2$, and

$(y_1, y_2) < (z_1, z_2) \implies y_1 + y_2 < z_1 + z_2$

$\implies x_1 + x_2 + y_1 + y_2 < y_1 + y_2 + z_1 + z_2$

$\implies x_1 + x_2 < z_1 + z_2$

$\implies (x_1, x_2) < (z_1, z_2)$

Therefore, transitivity is satisfied.

This is an ordered relation because the axioms above are both satisfied.

Is the solution above correct? I feel as though I made a mistake or just made an incorrect conclusion somewhere. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I think so far so good, but you should also verify that the relation is compatible with addition and multiplication.

Comment: @Berci Could you elaborate on what you mean by compatible with addition and multiplication?

Comment: I guess the statement is that it's an ordered field. For that you need 1. $F$ is a field, 2. $a<b\implies a+c<b+c$ and 3. whenever $c>0$, then $a<b\implies ac<bc$.